# Detectar cuando un usuario se está redirigiendo a otra página web que no es la mía con javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber como detecto que el usuario está saliendo de mi página para dirigirse a otra que no es la mía con javascript. Supongamos que mi página es [www.mipagina.com](http://www.mipagina.com), y el usuario decide abandonarla e ir a [www.clarin.com](http://www.clarin.com), siempre en la misma pestaña. Quiero detectar ese evento antes de que se vaya

Comment: vos queres detectar un cambio de pestaña o al hacer click en un link que se va a otro lado???

Comment: Supongamos que mi página es www.mipagina.com, y el usuario decide abandonarla e ir a www.clarin.com, siempre en la misma pestaña. Quiero detectar ese evento antes de que se vaya

Comment: Quieres algo como esto https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704533/13419694?

Comment: No exactamente, ese evento se dispararía también cuando navega por las distintas páginas dentro de mi sitio. Yo necesito que se dispare únicamente cuando se está yendo de mi sitio a otro.

Comment: No creo que se pueda... eso sería darle a mipagina.com información privada de hacia que otras paginas navego yo... por privacidad no creo que eso sea posible